# Removing a class from an nth-child

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

This is a fairly simple question I hope, I have a series of div's:

```
<div class="full">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="left">
```

I'm creating a print specific stylesheet and I need to remove the wrap class. I have achieved this with jQuery:

```
$(".printMe").click(function() {
    $("div.full > div:nth-child(1)").removeClass("wrap");
    window.print();
});
```

But this affects the whole look of my page.

Is there any way I can achieve the above in CSS only so I can place in my print.css page?

print.css is referenced within my html as:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="idauthenticate/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just alter the CSS within your print.css? like: `.wrap { background-color:transparent; border: none; margin:0; padding:0;... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@media print {
    div.full > div:nth-child(1).wrap {
        /*remove styles here eg.*/
        border:0;
        padding:0;
    }
}
```